# Tag suggestion for the new kind of browsers extensions

Tags: discussion, tags, firefox

Can we have a "webextension" tag, (and/or a tag for E10s)?

PS: Saying "I disagree" if you disagree, is enough, no need to downvote every tag suggestion.

Comment: what would the tag wiki and tag wiki exerpts for this look like?

Comment: Why do we need this tag?  We can't recommend any specific web extension, sounds like, it will be a tag people will used when asking off topic questions.  Voting is the only way to show I disagree with this tag suggestion, so yes, I downvoted it.  Read up what downvotes mean on meta SE websites

Comment: @Quidam Its worth getting the "culture" of the place before judging its denizens - especially where *there's absolutely no* penalty from a MSU downvote. Calling us... all these things isn't *nice*. I've deleted those comments and recommend you try to keep your comments to the question, rather than about your dislike of the community as a whole.

Comment: Of course there are penalities! You are downvoted, you lose a lot of privileges, you lose a lot of functionalities on the site. So it's definitely not true there are no penalities.  There are a lot. If it was not the case, downvotes would make me nothing. We are really A LOT to feel hostility, it's not me alone, Newbies feel the community as being hostile, so you really think you don't judge by saying that? You judge people while saying people shouldn't judge? Is it a good behaviour rather to understand why this feeling arise? I'm not the one who make the poor reputation of SE.

Comment: @Quidam, the Meta sites are different.  Voting on Meta sites is how people express agreement or disagreement with a suggestion in a post.  It isn't personal, and doesn't affect your rep or privileges.

Answer (score 3):

The `webextension` tag would only be useful when used in conjunction with other more specific tags such as an actual product tag, as such it would be a meta tag.

Problems with programming issues for the `webextension` API interface would off-topic here and be better off on Stack Overflow.

I don't see a compelling reason to create this tag at the moment.